# Showing one-to-one and onto

Tags: functions

> Let $\alpha:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ be defined by $\alpha(n,m)=\frac{n}{m}$. Is this one to one? Is this onto?

I know that if $\alpha$ is one to one I must show $\alpha(n,m)=\alpha(n_1,m_1)$. In this case it at first seems trivial since $\frac{n}{m}=\frac{n_1}{m_1}$, but does this show that $\alpha$ is one to one?

I am also at a loss on how to show that this is onto. I have seen $\mathbb{Q} := \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z} - \{0\})$. So to me it seems that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is nearly the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ therefore it would be onto. However, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: To show it is 1-1, you must show that if $\alpha(p,q) = \alpha(r,s)$, then $(p,q) = (r,s)$. If true, this means that whenever $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{r}{s}$ where $p, q, r$, $s$ are integers, then $p=r$ and $s=q$. Is that true?

For onto, you must show that any rational number $\frac{n}{m}$ is $\alpha(something)$. Can you find a $(p,q)$ such that $\alpha(p,q) = \frac{n}{m}$?

Comment: Thank you for a speedy response! The way I see it is nothing guarantees $p=r$ and $s=q$ because 1/2 = 2/4. Yes there is a $p,q$ if $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: Yes, that's right. So the function is onto but not 1-1.